# Encrypt message using recursion, python

Tags: python, recursion, encryption

I need to write a recursive function  to encrypt a message by
converting all lowercase characters to the next character (with z transformed to a) in python.
This is my code so far, but I don't know how to go farther, or how to correct the error.

```
sentence = input("Enter a message: \n")
letter_number = 0

def encrypt_sentence (s, number):
    if letter_number == len(sentence) - 1:
       return(s)
    else:
        if s[letter_number] == chr(122):
            return encrypt_sentence(chr(ord(s[letter_number])-25), letter_number + 1)
        else:
            return encrypt_sentence(chr(ord(s[letter_number])+1), letter_number + 1)

print("Encrypted message")
print(encrypt_sentence(sentence, letter_number))
```

Comment: When you recurse, you're passing `ord(...)+1` as the `sentence` parameter.

Comment: `ord` returns an integer, and you're passing this integer as `sentence`. Integer aren't lists of something; 5[2] doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed your code and now it works.

```
sentence = input("Enter a message: \n")
letter_number = 0

def encrypt_sentence (sentence):
    if sentence:
        if sentence == chr(122):
            return chr(ord(sentence[letter_number])-25)
        else:
            return chr(ord(sentence[letter_number])+1)
print("Encrypted message")
ris = ''
for word in sentence:
    ris += encrypt_sentence(word)
print(ris)
```